# mysqli select from table join table 2 confusion

Tags: php, mysqli

what im trying to do is : i have table ->`members` and table `follow_user`. so when an logged in user visit some profile and click on `follow button` the function `INSERT INTO` inserts `loggedin` user's id and profile 's id into follow_user table till now all good. but the big confusion im having is that , fetching all `followers from database` for current viewing profile and display their `name`,`profilepic`,`id` on currently viewing user's profile .this is the code im trying to user but can't go above the select statement :

```
<?php
include("../secure/functions.php");
$currentid =$_SESSION['user_id'];

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$viewuser =$_GET['id'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM follow_user JOIN members WHERE     follow_user.follow_id = ? OR members.id = ?"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $viewuser); // Bind "$user_id" to parameter.
    $stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
    $stmt->store_result();
     if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
     $stmt->bind_result($id,$username,$user_level,$profilepic,$cover); // get    variables from result.
       $stmt->fetch();
}
}

?>
```

table structures :

follow_user

```
column  type           Null Default Comments
fid         int(11)         No       
id          varchar(300)    No       
follow_id   varchar(300)    No
```

members :

```
column  Type           Null      Default    Comments
id          int(11)     No       
username    varchar(30) No       
email       varchar(50) No       
password    char(128)   No       
salt        char(128)   No       
user_level  varchar(50) No       
profilepic  varchar(200)    No       
cover       varchar(50) No
```

Comment: You did not specify what you are joining on. The syntax is `JOIN table_name ON join_condition`.

Comment: how it should be ? any sample?

Comment: Edit your question and add the structure of your two tables, then I can give you the exact query instead of a sample.

Comment: please see edited question for structure

Answer (score 0):

Add the join condition to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM follow_user JOIN members ON members.id = follow_user.fid WHERE ....
```

Comment: what should be in WHERE? Myabe like : WHERE id= ? ,, $viewuser

Comment: That's the data filter you want to use. It depends on what you want to achieve, and it can be removed altogether if you want to fetch all records. The one you currently have is probably good `follow_user.follow_id = ?`.

Comment: im getting error : Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\video\profile.php on line 23

Answer (score -1):

There are two parameters in the query, but you have bound one. The second `?` is empty when executing the query. Simply add a new `$stmt->bind_param('s', $viewuser);` is your solution.

Or make the stuff more readable by using the next

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM follow_user JOIN members WHERE follow_user.follow_id = :followId OR members.id = :memberId"); 
$stmt->bind_param(':followId', $viewuser);
$stmt->bind_param(':memberId', $viewuser);
$stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
```

Please note the `:followId` and `:memberId` as parameters. The prepared statements isn't built to bind one value to multiple parameters.

Also, if you want to combine tables correctly (from developer view), i suggest to use either `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` if there are FK (foreign key) relationships.

Comment: I am afraid you aren't too familiar with mysqli prepared statements